# Setting up ec2 instance of ubuntu 10.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to set up an ubuntu 10.04 instance on ec2, but there are some instance ready available I tried with few but I am not really happy with that since those are meant for test puporse.

I have to deploy a java/j2ee based web app with mysql.
1)need to install tomcat
2)java runtime 6
3) apache web server

What would be the best image to use for my requirement and I initially planning to launch with the micro instance if my web app demands I may further move to small and larger instances. So it should be eligible for free usuage tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note with the Micro instances, I found they can be prone to crashing when installing the Sun JDK 6 due to resource limitations. The workaround for that is to setup the image on a larger instance size and when finished make a snapshot and run up that snapshot on the micro.

Note that only the 64 bit Ubuntu images run on the micro instances, so make sure you pick a 64-bit Ubuntu image if a micro instance is your target size.

Comment: Ya david I am aware of that I was fighting with 32 bit instance. Now I have to start everything now

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://alestic.com/) has the AMI codes for the official Canonical Ubuntu AMI's.
Where I work, we're using one of those on a micro instance, in the free usage tier.

Comment: But the official images doesnt have small instance, if I want to install Java and Jdk on that then I guess I need to spend lot of money for that.